# DockPanel Suite Menu and Tool strip Theme not applied when Switching among Themes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, themes, dockpanel-suite

I am using DockPanel Suite Version 2.12.0. When I move over DARK/LIGHT/BLUE, Menu and Tool strip theme applied correctly at first time, from second time onward light theme applied to Menu and Tool strip. I have also checked with DockSample same case. This question is applicable to withing Schema:VS2012,2013 and 2015. If i switch between Schema, i.e, 2012 to 2013, it is working as expected.

How fix this?

Comment: Has been reported. Will be fixed soon.

Comment: Fixed in 2.13. The latest release is already 2.16.1.